# Angular (1.5) handle JSON errors from $http called with responseType blob

Tags: angularjs

I ran into an issue with **$http** called with **responseType: blob**.
I would like to handle errors response in JSON but I get blob data instead even if I set the response's content-type as 'application/json' on the server.

```
$http.post(url, data, {responseType: 'blob'})
  .then(function(response) {
    // download the file  (works fine)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle JSON response error
  });
```

Is there any way to do that without trying to [convert error data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052567/how-to-read-json-error-response-from-http-if-responsetype-is-arraybuffer) to object?

Comment: .then() function can be used in a more efficient manner... .then(function(response){},function(error){ console.log(error);}); In the console.log() you will get it in the manner you want it to. and then you can handle it.

Comment: Thanks but the convention on my project is to use then().catch() instead of then(onSuccess, onError). Unfortunately it doesn't change the fact that the data in the onError callback remains blob type.

Comment: can you try                                                                               $http({method: 'GET', url: Restangular.one('attachments', idAtt).getRestangularUrl(),
        headers: {'X-Auth-Token': token}, responseType: 'blob'}).then(function(response) {
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(response.data);
        window.open(url);
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have different content types for success and error cases, but you can manage conversion in single place. Write `responseError` [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) where you can check if `error.data` is `instanceof Blob` and convert it to JSON

Comment: Hi Aleskey, I've already fixed it with an `interceptor` and `readAsText` method of `FileReader` but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do that.